# Is there a poison that causes a temporary paralysis?

Tags: medicine, medical, poisons

I am writing a story where characters have been dosed with a small amount of poison, with the result being a temporary paralysis.

The information I need is more along the lines of possible treatment, as I'm wanting to use the information to highlight another character's medical prowess.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Jacob*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Many anesthesics will do that. I don't see how this question is related to world building though.

Answer (score 5):

Most poisons that cause paralysis are lethal by cardiac arrest or asphyxia.

For the ones that last for a short time, your medical characters could show their prowess by keeping the poisoned ones alive for the critical fifteen-twenty minutes the drug acts. In this range, you have [Succinyl choline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suxamethonium_chloride) and [Curare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curare) as possible poisons.

Belladonna and Hemlock are neuromuscular toxins and can cause paralysis. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3361210/) and [here](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/821362-treatment) you can read the treatments.

Finally, wolfsbane and foxglove also cause symptons similar to paralysis. Both are very pretty flowers you could have in your garden without raising suspicion. The treatments for the poisons (aconite and digitalis) are easy to find in medical web sites like [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19514874) and [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4816869/)